# importing vanilla js to React is causing event listeners to duplicate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm integrating an HTML/CSS/JS template on a React SPA.

JS script (functions.js) uses jQuery to add event listeners when the script loads on multiple tags dynamically (`$(p).addClass('.center')`)

In order for it to work, the script must be added using useEffect for it to add the listeners when the component finishes rendering (in every component). Doing that, changing the route will replicate the event listeners already there for the parent component, thus, creating lag and unexpected behaviors in the app.

Here's what I have tried so far:

- Having the script in index.html doesn't solve the problem. index.html loads only once, changing the route doesn't execute the script again.
- Loading the script when the route changes add more duplicated event listeners since you can't destroy the old ones when the component dismounts.

Some advice on approaches I should try can help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not recommended, and maybe not possible.

You *should* not manipulate the DOM from outside of React (including adding event handlers).

Anyway, you can *add* an extra script to a React-App, but you can not *remove* the script again. If this extra script is adding event handlers (and doesn't remove them),
then you can not remove the event handlers.

(You can not remove an added script because adding an extra script means
basically to execute some extra Javascript code, which can do whatever
it wants, including adding variables and functions, and even modify existing objects. You can not simply *undo* that.)

#### solutions (or not)

To achieve what you want you probably **need to modify the imported script**:

- You can make the imported script manage the event handlers (i.e. removing them), or
- you can give React the control over these event handlers (i.e. re-implement them in React),
  and e.g. only keep the callbacks inside the imported script.

(Furthermore, you *should* make sure the script is only loaded once.)

#### Probably bad ideas:

If you can not remove event handlers, you may be able to remove the DOM nodes where the event handlers are attached to.
But working with the same DOM from React and from a separate script is likely to cause problems.

One might think of extracting the components that need the event handlers, and destroy them and recreate
them everytime you need a new event handler. But that sounds quite dirty to me,
and I would expect any kind of other errors later, including possibly memory leaks.
You would still re-load the same script file over and over again, only to attach a different event handler.
Old references to the DOM nodes might still stay in memory.

Comment: Really thorough answer, thanks for the help.

Comment: I have already integrated the last solution (destroying all listeners using $("body").find("*").off(); every time the route changes, a really dirty one that I will be replacing soon), works perfectly to this moment, but I'm pretty sure things will go south the moment I start adding more logic to the app.

Comment: oh, interesting ... I must admit that I'm not very familiar with jQuery, I have to read about the .off() method. I didn't know jQuery can just remove "all" event handlers (as opposed to specific ones, of which a reference is available). IMO that is still a bit dirty, but cleaner than my "bad" solution.